# How to install Multisite WordPress like www.mysite.com/de instead of www.de.mysite.com

Tags: wordpress

I know how to install multisite in WordPress using the following code in config.php page:

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

It will then create a subdirectory structure domain like:

> [www.de.mysite.com](http://www.de.mysite.com)

but how can I make the URL like

> www.mysite/de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map your domain to your website any way you like in the multisite admin panel. Just follow the instructions on this page: https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/#update-wordpress